# Can you use a Rails Engine with a JS Framework like Vue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, rails-engines, blacklight

I want to do a project with https://github.com/projectblacklight/blacklight
Can I use it as a Rails API with a Vue frontend?

It is a Rails Engine that returns JSON but it is traditionally used in a Rails app as a Plugin / Gem (really it's an engine which is similar).

https://github.com/projectblacklight/blacklight/wiki
Every Blacklight search provides JSON, RSS, and Atom Responses of search results

Comment: https://github.com/rails/webpacker#vue

Comment: If you are pursuing webpacker + vue, you can generate a new Vue on Rails with the following application template ~> `rails new app -m vueonrails.com/vue`

Answer (score 0):

I am researching this and so far I think the answer is yes.
Jason Coyne from Stanford built an [App using Ember with Blacklight](https://github.com/jcoyne/ember_blacklight)

Here are some more discussions around the question.
+ https://github.com/projectblacklight/blacklight/wiki/JSON-API
+ https://github.com/projectblacklight/blacklight/pull/588
+ https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/blacklight-development/TIYCjemfp3A

There is not a lot of documentation about this that I can find.

Answer (score 0):

[blacklight-vue](https://github.com/projectblacklight/blacklight-vue) is an engine made explicitly for this purpose. [blacklight-vue-demo](https://github.com/projectblacklight/blacklight-vue-demo) is a sample build with this engine. The generic answer for building any Ruby on Rails application with Vue is to use the [Webpacker gem](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/integrations.md#vue).